# User card reputation score doesn't match that of reputation before hover

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation, user-card

Before hovering the user card indicates I have a reputation of 10.4k. When I hover over my user card it shows that I have a reputation of 10.3k. Currently my actual [reputation on Stack Overflow is at 10,351](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61654/ahsteele?tab=reputation). To ensure it's not a client side issue I've cleared my browser cache.

Here are some screenshots of the user cards:

[image: 10.4k user card] compared to [image: 10.3k user card]

Is the same rounding algorithm ***not*** being used in both places? Is there some server side caching of the expanded user card?

Comment: Caching. It's always caching. And I see 10.4.

Comment: Yeah - what he ^^^^ said.

Comment: @MartijnPieters and now I too see 10.4k. I'll leave this here as it seems like wherever it is being cached should at least attempt to have the two user card rep values match.

Comment: @ahsteele: with the asynchronous nature of the HTTP protocol that's almost impossible.

Comment: @Oded is it really norepro? Seems more like by design?

Comment: We use no-repro for transient things like this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters really? The value is stored somewhere regardless of the synchronicity of the requests. Obviously if previously requested and cached it is going to be different than a more recently retrieved number. That said when I clear my local cache and re-request my expanded user card I should get a fresh one. That being the case it should be rendering with the same value that is provided by the user card that was rendered with the question. Or am I missing your point?

Comment: @ahsteele: this is really transient, it's not a big deal and the site is full of places caching can lead to temporary inconsistencies. It doesn't matter that much, does it?

Comment: @oded sounds good.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh it matters! :-P Yeah it really doesn't matter just wanted to throw it out there in-case there was a "real" issue.

Comment: @ahsteele: And no, re-rendering everything every time your score changes would put too great a burden on the web servers. There is a non-zero cost rendering your usercard.

Comment: @MartijnPieters not understanding the underlying caching mechanism I cannot argue the point, but I certainly was not advocating a re-rendering of a rep score on a request. We could take this chat to discuss, but I'm good. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usercard is loaded separately, over AJAX. This request is therefore also *cached* separately. The page was rendered afresh for you, your usercard was still being cached with an old score.

For your usercard, the URL used is:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/user-info/61654
```

which currently shows that you have a reputation of 10.4k. Just wait a while and the cache will update to show your new reputation score.